# Expand total width of form boxes on one line to 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a form and I have several input boxes on the same line.

I'd like to have the email input to take one line. The date, time, and number inputs to take another line. However, I'm not sure how to get the *date/time/number* inputs to span exactly 100% of the width of the form.

The percentages I have now in the CSS are estimates, so the edge of the number box doesn't vertically align with the email input box.

```css
input[type=email] {
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=date] {
  width: 22%;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
input[type=time] {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
input[type=number] {
  width: 11.4%
}
```

```html
<form>
  Email: <input type="email"><br>
  Date: <input type="date">
  Time: <input type="time">
  Number in Party: <input type="number">
</form>
```

Comment: Please see my updated answer and example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it using flex, Here's a working [example](http://jsbin.com/yalesihodo/edit?html,css,output)

I wrapped each line on a div, like this:

```
<form>
  <div>Email: <input type="email"></div>
  <div>
    <div>Date: <input type="date"></div>
    <div>Time: <input type="time"></div>
    <div>Number in Party: <input type="number"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

css

```
form{

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form>div{
  display: flex;
}

form>div input{
  flex-grow: 1;
}

form>div>div{
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I changed my code so that the date/time/num are contained in one div, display:flex and justify-content:space-between. However, the boxes don't vertically align with the email box, even when the with of the email box is set to 100%. There aren't any margins set. Do you know how I could fix this?
(Here's what it looks like: http://imgur.com/AUBQpCv)

Comment: glad that helped, I can't visualize what you mean, can you provide a fiddle for that?

Comment: Can you illustrate (using mspaint or something) on an image what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Here's a link to the entire form, HTML, and CSS: http://imgur.com/a/kCvh4

Notice how the name, phone number, and email input boxes don't line up with the end of the number in party box and submit button? I can't figure out what's wrong/how to fix this.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Sure. Try to implement your code like my html, you need to wrap each line on a div

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<label>` to give yourself some explicit control the `width`, `padding` & `margin` of the form field labels.

**Example:**

```css
label, input {
display: inline-block;
height: 24px;
line-height: 24px;
}

label {
width: 18%;
margin: 6px 0;
padding: 3px 0 3px 3px;
background-color: rgb(227,227,227);
}

input {
width: 80%;
}

input:nth-of-type(n+2) {
width: 13%;
}
```

```html
<form>
<label for="email">Email:</label><input type="email" name="email" id="email"><br />
<label for="date">Date:</label><input type="date" name="date" id="date">
<label for="time">Time:</label><input type="time" name="time" id="time">
<label for="number">Number in Party:</label><input type="number" name="number" id="number">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[type=email] {
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=date] {
  width: 21%;
  
}
input[type=time] {
  width: 21%;
   margin-right:42px;
}
input[type=number] {
 
  width: 20.9%;
    
  
}
```

```html
<form>
  Email: <input type="email"><br><br>
  Date : <input type="date">
  Time : <input type="time">
  Number in Party : <input type="number">
</form>
```